# Prevent MouseUp/MouseClick from happening after MouseDown

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

We're using [GMA MouseHook](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook) for an elaborate Outlook VSTO AddIn.
Because of the complicated nature of our AddIn, we kinda developed ourselves into a corner on certain issues.

**Our Problem:**
We have Outlook maximized and the Mail.Compose window is also maximized on top of it. If we click the close-button on the Mail.Compose Window, we call the actual window-close in the MouseDown-Event.
Now the Mail.Compose window closes and the MouseUp + MouseClick events are firing on the close-button of the underlying Outlook mainwindow.

I tried setting the MouseEventArgs' **e.Handled = True**, but it still executes the MouseUp + MouseClick events after.

Any Ideas on how to solve this?

**EDIT** Thanks mehrdad safa for pointing me in the right direction!
Here is how I solved my problem:

First, I created (e.g. copied and pasted from the web) this class:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class MouseInterceptor

    Public Delegate Function CallBack( _
    ByVal nCode As Integer, _
    ByVal wParam As IntPtr, _
    ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer

    'Declare the mouse hook constant.
    'For other hook types, obtain these values from Winuser.h in Microsoft SDK.
    Dim WH_MOUSE As Integer = 7
    Shared hHook As Integer = 0

    'Keep the reference so that the delegate is not garbage collected.
    Private hookproc As CallBack

    'Import for the SetWindowsHookEx function.
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Overloads Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx _
          (ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal HookProc As CallBack, _
           ByVal hInstance As IntPtr, ByVal wParam As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    'Import for the CallNextHookEx function.
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Overloads Shared Function CallNextHookEx _
          (ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal nCode As Integer, _
           ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function
    'Import for the UnhookWindowsHookEx function.
    <DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
    Public Overloads Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx _
              (ByVal idHook As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    'Point structure declaration.
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> Public Structure Point
        Public x As Integer
        Public y As Integer
    End Structure

    'MouseHookStruct structure declaration.
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> Public Structure MouseHookStruct
        Public pt As Point
        Public hwnd As Integer
        Public wHitTestCode As Integer
        Public dwExtraInfo As Integer
    End Structure

    Public Shared Function MouseHookProc( _
    ByVal nCode As Integer, _
    ByVal wParam As IntPtr, _
    ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
        Dim MyMouseHookStruct As New MouseHookStruct()

        If (nCode < 0) Then
            Return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam)
        End If

        MyMouseHookStruct = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, MyMouseHookStruct.GetType()), MouseHookStruct)

        Return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam)

    End Function
```

Then I just call it in my MouseDown Event BEFORE closing the Window:

```
MouseInterceptor.MouseHookProc(0, "0x201", 0)
```

The first param tells the Hook if the system should continue with other events if the value is < 0. So I use 0 to stop after MouseDown. The second param means "Left Mouse Button Down", the thirs param seems to indicate if it is a single or double click. I just left it at 0 for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a callback for `LowLevelMouseProc` using `setWindowsHook` function to handle global mouse event. then you can prevent sending mouse up event back to windows and other applications. just don't call `callNextHook` function to prevent windows to forward the message!

use this example:

```
class InterceptMouse  

{  

private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;  

private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;  

public static void Main()  

{  

    _hookID = SetHook(_proc);  

    Application.Run();  

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);  

}  

private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)  

{  

    using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())  

    using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)  

    {  

        return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,  

            GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);  

    }  

}  

private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam,   IntPtr lParam);  

private static IntPtr HookCallback(  

    int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)  

{  

    if (nCode >= 0 &&  

        MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)  

    {  

        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct =   (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));  

        Console.WriteLine(hookStruct.pt.x + “, ” + hookStruct.pt.y);  

    }  

    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);  

}  

private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;  

private enum MouseMessages  

{  

    WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,  

    WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,  

    WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,  

    WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,  

    WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,  

    WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205  

}  

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  

private struct POINT  

{  

    public int x;  

    public int y;  

}  

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  

private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT  

{  

    public POINT pt;  

    public uint mouseData;  

    public uint flags;  

    public uint time;   

    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;  

}  

[DllImport(“user32.dll”, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]  

private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,  

    LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);  

[DllImport(“user32.dll”, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]  

[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]  

private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);  

[DllImport(“user32.dll”, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]  

private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,  

    IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);  

[DllImport(“kernel32.dll”, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]  

private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
```

}

Warning: preventing mouse up event from happening may occurs unexpected further problems.